# How to add polymorphic props in React using Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

How can I add polymorphic props to a React component?

I have tried the following, but it results in:

`T. This type is incompatible with some incompatible instantiation of T`

Example:

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react';

type Props<T> = {
  promise: () => Promise<T>
}

export default class Async<T> extends React.Component {
    props: Props<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange error, you can try this instead

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react';

type Props<T> = {
  promise: () => Promise<T>
}

export default class Async<T> extends React.Component<*, Props<T>, *> {}
```